# Accessing Google Sheets API with Python and keep getting dailyLImitsExceededUnreg error

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I keep getting the following error when trying to access the Google Sheets API.  It was working before hand, but now this keeps happening. I've checked the quotas, I've recreated the projects and the credentials files, and I've made sure that the Google Sheets API and Google Drive API are enabled.  I've included these scope items:

DEFAULT_SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

I'm currently using Google.oauth2 module since the oauth2client module has been deprecated.

Could someone please help me out with this? Please let me know if you need more info.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<filepath>", line 19, in <module>
    cleaned_results = spud.parse_update(search_results)
  File "<filepath>", line 91, in parse_update
    latest_data = Spud.sheet_manager.get_column()
  File "<filepath>", line 49, in get_column
    worksheet = self._get_worksheet(worksheet_number)
  File "<filepath>", line 33, in _get_worksheet
    spreadsheet = self.client.open(self.sheet_name)
  File "<filepath>", line 123, in open
    self.list_spreadsheet_files()
  File "<filepath>", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
    res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
  File "<filepath>", line 79, in request
    raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide your whole script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: As @Tanaike said, please provide some code so it gets easier to troubleshoot the error